# How to measure the bandwidth of IPC

Tags: bandwidth, ipc

I need to do some measure about communication between two processes in my Ubuntu server.

Saying that the two processes are process A and process B. A keeps sending data to B.

I need to get two kinds of data about statistics:
1) the max value of bandwidth of IPC (Inter-process communication).
2) how many KB/s data is sent from A to B in a specific duration.
With the two kinds of data above, I can know if the bandwidth of IPC invokes some limit or not.

Is there some tool which can help me?

Comment: I didn't know there was such a thing.  I'd thought the only limits would be the performance of both programmes communicating.